# How to interpret the equation of motion of a point that changes its acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

I'm trying to understand more deeply the equations of motion for a constantly accelerated 1D motion.

Consider a point that moves with constant acceleration $a$ and that, at a certain moment $\tau$ changes its acceleration to $b$. Its equations of motion should be (by integration):

$$x(t)=\begin{cases} x_o+v_o t+\frac{a}{2} t^2\mid t<\tau\\ x_o'+v_o'(t-\tau)+\frac{b}{2}(t-\tau)^2\mid t>\tau \end{cases}$$

With $x_o$ and $v_o$ the initial positions and velocities when the motion begins.

Focusing on the second equation, for $t>\tau$, and writing it explicitly:

$x(t)= x_o+v_o \tau+\frac{a}{2} \tau^2+(v_o+a\tau)(t-\tau)+\frac{b}{2}(t-\tau)^2=$

$=x_o+v_o \tau+\frac{a}{2} \tau^2+v_ot-v_o\tau+a\tau t-a\tau^2+\frac{b}{2}t^2+\frac{b}{2}\tau^2-b\tau t=$

$=(v_o+a\tau-b\tau) t+ \frac{b}{2} t^2+(x_o+v_o\tau-v_o\tau+\frac{a}{2} \tau^2-a\tau^2+\frac{b}{2}\tau^2)=$

$=(v_o+a\tau-b\tau) t+ \frac{b}{2} t^2+(x_o-\frac{a}{2} \tau^2+\frac{b}{2}\tau^2)=$

$=(v_o+\tau(a-b)) t+ \frac{b}{2} t^2+(x_o+\frac{b-a}{2} \tau^2)$

How to interpret this correclty?

Is $(v_o+\tau(a-b))$ the velocity of the point at $\tau$  and $(x_o+\frac{b-a}{2} \tau^2)$ its position?

If so why these two have such expressions? I'm quite confused about the meaning of this last expression, can someone give any suggestion?

Comment: You are making your life way too hard. At time $\tau$ the body is in one position $x_\tau$ and it has one velocity $v_\tau$. Use that information to simplify your expressions and write everything in dependence of $(t-\tau)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take your final expression

$$
x(t) = \underbrace{\left(x_0 + \frac{b - a}{2}\tau^2\right)}_{x_0^*} + \underbrace{\left(v_0 + \tau(a - b)\right)}_{v_0^*} t + \frac{b}{2} t^2, \quad \text{with}\ t>\tau,
$$

then $x_0^*$ and $v_0^*$ would be the position and velocity at $t=0$, however this is only meaningful if $\tau<0$ (however in that case $x_0$ and $v_0$ would be meaningless). But you can also view it as tracing back the motion if the acceleration would be kept constant at $b$, which results in two parabolas touching at $t=\tau$:

[image: Two touching parabolas.]

Velocity changes linearly with time. So when $\tau>0$ $v_0^*$ can be interpreted as the initial velocity, plus the change in velocity from $t=0$ to $t=\tau$ due to acceleration $a$ and minus the change in velocity from $t=0$ to $t=\tau$ due to acceleration $b$ because you trace back the velocity to $t=0$. A similar argument can be made for $\tau<0$.

In order to understand the expression for $x_0^*$ you have to remember that the two parabolas are touching, so both position and velocity at $t=\tau$ are the same for both parabolas. Now by looking at the position difference by going back the first curve from $t=\tau$ to $t=0$ compared to then going back along the other curve from $t=\tau$ to $t=0$ you get,

$$
\Delta x = x_0^* - x_0 = \left(x_\tau - v_\tau \tau - \frac{a}{2}\tau^2\right) - \left(x_\tau - v_\tau \tau - \frac{b}{2}\tau^2\right) = \frac{b - a}{2}\tau^2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it's worth noting that such a discontinuity can never be 100 % real. To go from acceleration $a$ to $b$ *instantaneously* ($\Delta t = 0$) would  require an instantaneous change in the net force responsible for the accelerations and that isn't possible in the material world.

Secondly, I think you are over-thinking your problem. Just write the kinematic equations for the three time regions:

1. For $t<\tau$:

$$x(t)=x_0+v_0t+\frac12 at^2$$
$$v(t)=v_0+at$$

2. For $t=\tau$:

$$x(\tau)=x_0+v_0\tau+\frac12 a\tau^{2}$$
$$v(\tau)=v_0+a\tau$$

3. For $t>\tau$:

$$x(t)=x(\tau)+v(\tau)(t-\tau)+\frac12b(t-\tau)^2$$
$$v(t)=v(\tau)+b(t-\tau)$$

> If so why these two have such expressions? I'm quite confused about the meaning of this last expression, can someone give any suggestion?

You don't need them: position and speed at $t=\tau$ are given by the equations under 2. Insert them into the equations under 3. to find position and speed for $t>\tau$. Each of the equations only applies in the applicable time interval but that is the nature of discontinuities.